# Pagination not work on page but work on category

Tags: pagination

i am using kriesi Pagination, it is working perfectly fine category page but it when i do similar query on page then it is not working. any idea why ?

```
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2){  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  
 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1) echo "<a class='prev' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages) echo "<a class='next' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
```

}

my page query is

> ```
>     <?php query_posts(array('category_name' => 'm-directory',
>                           'meta_key'=> 'mno',
>                          'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
>                          'order'=> 'ASC')); if ( have_posts() ) :
> while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>       <li class="post">  
>      ...
>    </li>  <?php endwhile;  kriesi_pagination(); ?>     <?php else : ?> <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p> <?php
> ```
>
> endif; ?>

Comment: Did my initial answer help? How about the revised one? Please be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is working perfectly fine on category page but when I do similar
>   query on page, then it is not working

I can see why you used [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) — your pagination function (`kriesi_pagination()`) uses the main query (the global `$wp_query` variable) to get the number of pages for your query, so you thought that altering the main query using `query_posts()` would make the pagination work, right?

And basically, it would. But your query args is missing the `paged` parameter — more details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22Paged.22_Parameter_to_a_Query).

Nonetheless, there's no need to use `query_posts()` because your custom pagination function actually allows passing a *custom number of pages* which is the first parameter for the function.

Therefore, just make a new instance of [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and pass the value of the instance's `$max_num_pages` property (i.e. `WP_Query::$max_num_pages`) to the pagination function:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( [
    // .. your args here.
    'paged' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
] );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();

        // .. your code.
    endwhile;
endif;

kriesi_pagination( $query->max_num_pages );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

### Additional Notes

- Every time you make a custom/secondary instance of `WP_Query` **and calls `the_post()`** (or `setup_postdata()`), make sure to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) after your loop ends, so that the *global* `$post` variable is restored back to the current post in the main query. Otherwise, for example, the next call to `the_title()` to display the title of the current post in the main query, you'd see the title of the last post in the above query and not the supposedly main query.
- You should also know that on category/archive/search/etc. "plural" pages, the `$wp_query->max_num_pages` value could be 2 or more depending on the total number of posts in the main query and the posts per page setting (which defaults to `10`). So if by "my page", you mean a Page (i.e. a post of the `page` type) which is a singular post, then the `$wp_query->max_num_pages` would always be `1`. And that might be the answer to "any idea why ?" in the question.
- If `kriesi_pagination()` still doesn't work for you, you can try using [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/):

  ```php
  echo paginate_links( [
      'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
      'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
  ] );
  ```

And last but not least, **avoid using `query_posts()`** as the WordPress core team suggested:

> Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be
>   problematic and should be avoided wherever possible. **In most cases,
>   there are better, more performant options for modifying the main query
>   such as via
>   the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action
>   within `WP_Query`**.

Happy coding!